# Edit a view in EspoCrm

Tags: php, json, backbone.js, crm, espocrm

I need to edit a view in EspoCrm. Should i inherit it from excisting, or just edit? Used [documentation](https://www.espocrm.com/documentation/development/custom-views/), but nothing happens.
I added views and recordViews fields in `custom/Espo/Custom/Resources/metadata/clientDefs/Contact.json`
then created `client/custom/src/views/Contact/record/detail.js`,
but it has no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `custom/Espo/Custom/Resources/metadata/clientDefs/Contact.json` file has to contain such code

```
{
  "recordViews": {
    "detail": "custom:views/contact/record/detail"
  }
}
```

Check if json is valid.

Rename your folder Contact to contact (lower case)
new path has to be `client/custom/src/views/contact/record/detail.js`

You need to inherit it from some class, `'view'` at least. But better is from `'crm:views/contact/record/detail'`, because you don't lose the main functionality. But it is not necessary. You can use general class `'views/record/detail'`as well.

In this case this file start with

```
Espo.define('custom:views/contact/record/detail', 'crm:views/contact/record/detail', function (Dep) {
```

Don't forget to rebuild EspoCRM in Administration.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful